# Deploying Spring Boot Application to Tomcat 8

Tags: spring-boot, war, archlinux, tomcat8

I have a Spring Boot application which works fine if I use the provided jar file. But when I try to deploy it as a war file to Tomcat 8 - it fails to work. I get the following output:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=server, ignoreInvalidF
                ields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:133)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:124)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringB
                ootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:81)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
                at org
                .apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:
                614)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunn
                able.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=server, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
                at org.spring
                framework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
                at org.springfra
                mework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java
                :299)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:209)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:73)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:234)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(Emb
                eddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
                ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=server, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
                at org.
                springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
                ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=server, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:304)
                at org.spring
                framework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:251)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factor
                y.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
                ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1405)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.Vali
                datorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1381)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:542)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
                at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:92)
                at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:768)
                at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:286)
                at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:255)
                at o
                rg.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:227)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:297)
                ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
                at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:56)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:137)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:46)
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.is
                Reachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1396)
                ... 94 common frames omitted
                2015-10-17 21:32:00.194  INFO 14049 --- [apr-8080-exec-4] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/bootstrap-3.2.0.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.20.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/angularjs-1.3.8.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/
                lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/angular-bootstrap-0.13.4.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/angular-route-1.4.7.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Invento
                ryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli-8.0.20.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomca
                t8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/var/lib/to
                mcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/org.json-chargebee-1.0.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-1.11.1.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webap
                ps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/InventoryAccounting/WEB-INF/lib/angular-1.4.7.jar]
                2015-10-17 21:32:00.196 ERROR 14049 --- [apr-8080-exec-4] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

My setup is on Arch Linux with MariaDB (MySQL), I am using gradle as a build tool. Here is my build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE")
        classpath("gradle.plugin.com.craigburke.gradle:jasmine-gradle:1.2.0")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.craigburke.jasmine'

jasmine {
    basePath = '/'
    files = [
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/master/1.3.8/angular.min.js',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/master/1.3.8/angular-route.min.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/master/1.3.8/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/main/resources/static/js/*',
        'src/main/resources/static/js/controllers/*',
        'src/test/resources/static/js/*.spec.js',
    ]
    additional = [
        colors: true
    ]
}

jar {
    baseName = 'InventoryAccounting'
}

war {
    baseName = 'InventoryAccounting'
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/resources'
            srcDir 'src/generated-resources'
        }
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "app.Application"
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13")

    compile("org.webjars:angularjs:1.3.8")
    compile("org.webjars.npm:angular-route:1.4.7")
    compile("org.webjars.bower:angular-bootstrap:0.13.4")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.2.0")
    compile("org.json:org.json:chargebee-1.0")

    testCompile("org.webjars:jasmine:2.0.0")
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.7'
}
```

And my application class looks like this:

```
package app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

For me, this is the important thing in the log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

But I have no idea what is causing that.
I can not seem to figure out what am I missing. Ideas?

Comment: Please extract the relevant exception from the log and copy it to your question AS code. This might already show you other questions adressing this problem. If not: try the search

Comment: @Marged I extracted what I could, check my edit.

Comment: @victor175 Just making sure, do you have the database configuration in your properties files?  Also, why are you using a lower version of JPA?

Comment: @ccit-spence The database configuration properties were set properly. About the JPA version - I checked out that it is used a lot and thought it is a stable one, I did not need anything bleeding edge in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering I fixed the issue. It happened after I added the following to my dependencies in my gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile("org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0")
    ...
}
```

I figured it out according to the log that I had. Hope this helps anyone having similar issues.